Signal Reconstruction with Local Peaks Preservation
I want to reconstruct a signal with the peaks preserved, while the background trend of the signal removed. At the same time, the small peaks of the signal are emphasized such that the they can be seen more clearly. The reconstructed signal should be as smooth as the original signal, as the two figures shown below.
Are there any methods to accomplish this task?
The first thoughts that come to my mind are:
(1) Wavelet transform where only the detail coefficients are used to reconstruct the signal. But it is not possible to emphasize the low peaks.
(2) Detect the location and amplitude of the peaks and then interpolate the signal using a, say Gaussian kernel, but this may create new peaks.
Any comments or reference would be greatly appreciated.

original signal

processed signal
Two test (original) signals, each of which is 359-point long is available in the github repository.

Can you share some signals? Like the 2 above as csv? I think I have a nice approach for that.

@Royi I don't know how to upload files so I paste a signal of 359 points directly in the post.

You can upload to GitHub Gist or any other GitHub repository. Google Drive / OneDrive link will work as well.

I added an implementation to the idea I have. Could you share more signals? Can you share the one you present above?

@Royi I uploaded another signal in the github. The signal is similar to the one of the figure but not the same become the experimental setup generating the signals changed.

Did you create the graph above in MATLAB? Could you share the recipe? It looks great!

The graph is not plotted in matlab. They are screenshots from an integrated equipment.

@Royi I think the peaks of the screenshots are nearly symmetrical about the local peak position, that may be why it looks great. Can this be formulated in the minimization problem?

I don't think such constraint can be formulated as a Convex constraint. I don't think it will have a significant effect as well.

Given the vector of samples $\boldsymbol{y}$ a reasonable model would be:
$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{z} \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| \boldsymbol{D}^{k} \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{1}, \; \text{ subject to } {x}_{i} = {y}_{i} \; \forall i \in \mathcal{P} $$
The model tries to achieve:

Sparsity of the $k$ derivative of the signal by using the ${L}_{1}$ norm.
This is achieved by applying the sparsity promoting norm, ${L}_{1}$, on the $k$ derivative of the signal as calculated by the finite differences operator $\boldsymbol{D}^{k}$. The parameter $\lambda$ controls how sparse the signal should be.
Signal, where it is not forced otherwise, should be close to "background trend" removed signal $\boldsymbol{z}$. I set $\boldsymbol{z}$ using either a DC Blocker or Rolling Median Filter.
Force local peak preservation by the equality constraints. The set $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of local peaks on a given radius. Actually, I define a peak in a radius $r$ to be a sample where no more than $\lfloor \sqrt{r} \rfloor$ samples have higher values.

The problem is a Convex Problem (Actually, it is both Strongly Convex and Strictly Convex as the Least squares term is both strongly and strictly convex). Hence can be solved efficiently.
Here are the results I got without fine tuning the parameters:


The local peaks are the peaks to preserve.

This is the trend signal estimated by the simple DC Blocker.
There are much more advanced methods to estimate such signal. Yet the signal you supplied is pretty simple.

The reconstructed signal has much more pronounced peaks which are preserved.
Another, more advanced approach, could be given by a sparse interpolation of the peaks as given by Build the Affinity Matrix of Edge Preserving Multi Scale Image Decomposition based on Local Extrema. It can be used either to solve the problem or estimate the DeTrend signal.

The code is available on my StackOverflow GitHub Repository (Look at the SignalProcessing\Q95393 folder).

Signal Detrending
There are many good questions on Trend Removal / Detrending / DeTrend / De Trend / Drift Removal of signals:

Filter Step Function Like Trend from a Signal.
How to estimate the local trend in a signal.
Filter the Drift in a Measured Strain Signal.

You may also look for Signal Decomposition.

This is really impressive. The peaks are more clearly seen after processed. Thank you very much. I downloaded your code but I have never used Julia. I tried to rewrite the code in Matlab but I don't know how to solve the optimization problem. Is there any closed-form solution to it so that I can write in plain codes in Matlab?

@ecook, It does not have a closed form solution. I can write an efficient solver (In MATLAB) probably. Though you may replicate the Julia code with CVX. If you need efficient solver, contact me by the email on the GitHub Project.

As long as one subtracts a trend/baseline whose slope is not constant (an offset, a line), the global derivative will change, hence the smoothness.
Many other posts have been interested in background/trend/drift removal. This is an ill-posed problem in general. However, with relatively narrow peaks, sparsity of the result, and positivity, can be optimized. With co-authors, we proposed BEADS: Baseline Estimation And Denoising with Sparsity; you can find codes in R, C++, Python, Matlab there. It uses the signal and its first and second derivatives. It may indeed help detect tiny peaks.

This method seems promising. I will try it. BTW, is it possible to emphasize the small peaks with some corrections to the algorithm?

There may be an issue at both ends. Something I did not put in the code. As for the emphasis, that's a very good question. As the algorithm is iterative, I would not include it at first inside the loops, but instead apply this once the baseline and noise are removed. There are plenty of techniques. Let me think that over

@LaurentDuval, I implemented BEADS in Julia. You may have a look at my 2nd answer :-). It is indeed a great method. Liked the paper and the derivation.

@Royi Great! I'll advertise it very soon

I got interested in BEADS and implemented it in Julia.
@Laurent Duval mentions it often, so it is probably worth checking out.
The paper defines the filter by 2 matrix operators.
It assumes they commute. It holds for the continuous case or for the periodic case for discrete signals (Circulant Matrices).
To handle the edges properly I added a smooth roll off on both sides to zero.
After that I applied the BEADS filter:

I think its baseline is good for this case as it has a parameter which prefers positive peaks which drives the baseline towards zero.
Hence I think using it as $\boldsymbol{z}$ in my other method could create a good and robust method to enhance the peaks.
The method is Convex which makes it robust.
There are many parameters, yet the paper suggest few insights on how to set them (I didn't use it though).
Julia have the features to farther optimize the method (Which is fast to begin with as the paper formulates the solve using Majorization Minimization).

The code is available on my StackOverflow GitHub Repository (Look at the SignalProcessing\Q95393 folder).
